# How to set android path and java path for appium

Tags: android, selenium, appium

This is what I have mentioned in my .bash_profile

> export JAVA_HOME=OS/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.8.25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
>
> export ANDROID_HOME=OS/Applications/android-sdk-macosx
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin

Error message in **APPIUM**:

> **✖ ANDROID_HOME is set but does not exist on the file system at "OS/Applications/android-sdk-macosx"

Answer (score 1):

For Java Environment path refer the below link.

http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/set-up-java-environment-variable-path/

For Android Environment path refer the below link.

http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/set-up-android-environment-path/